# get sharepoint public image using graph api

Tags: api, graph

I want to get a public URL to get the images of a list column using the graph API
When using the sharepoint REST API I could do it this way:

[https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/namesite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Jobs')/RenderListDataAsStream](https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/namesite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27Jobs%27)/RenderListDataAsStream)

```
"Image": {
            "fileName": "PM.png",
            "serverRelativeUrl": "/sites/sitename/SiteAssets/Lists/32621fcf-e08c-4e3e-91ee-73pfe37752pm8/BD.png",
            "id": "b21f223d-e9af-41d5-80a3-db89dd7b10d2",
            "serverUrl": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com",
            **"thumbnailRenderer": {
                "spItemUrl": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.1/drives/b!Gtl2BVcgkW_CHn3DwqYuAqWL0zDWtdEi1xPlBGSybE19ol3o3brR6hD0A5zU1Vr/items/01365JYLYB5EIP3FL7J2VAYBI63RHOXJHST",**
                "fileVersion": 2,
                "sponsorToken": "P2VPDdGVzL3Rlc3RsYW5kaW5nL0xpc3RzL1N1YiBTZWN0aW9ufEltYWdlfka"
            }
        },
```

I got the thumbnailRenderer->spItemUrl this when doing another query to that url brings me a public url with a token and this is the one that allowed me to get the image
but I can't replicate this using graph API

Beforehand thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can extract from the "spItemUrl" the drive id and the drive item id.

With them, you can use graph api:

```
graphClient.Drives[pDriveId].Items[pDriveItemId].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```